# Will my UITableViewDelegate code cause leaks or fails?

Tags: swift, uitableview

- I have a Table, selecting a cell takes you to a Detail, and completing a task on Detail updates the Table.
- I commented on the 2 concerning lines: will this code cause memory leaks because of keeping a reference, and will it fail to reload the table because of a missing assignment/reference?

Table:

```swift
class ShabbosLevelsViewController: UITableViewController, RemoteTableReloadDelegate {
    var completedLevelsArray: [Int]!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        completedLevelsArray = UserDefaults...
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ...
        cell.levelNumberLabel.text = "Level \(indexPath.row + 1)"
        if completedLevelsArray.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.levelNumberLabel.text?.append("DONE")
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        showLevelFor(indexPath)
    }

    func showLevelFor(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let shabbosVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: Const.shabbosViewController) as! ShabbosViewController
        shabbosVC.remoteDelegate = tableView.delegate as? any RemoteTableReloadDelegate // Concerning line 1/2
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(shabbosVC, animated: true)
    }

    func reload() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Protocol:

```swift
protocol RemoteTableReloadDelegate: AnyObject {
    func reload()
}
```

Detail:

```swift
class ShabbosViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var remoteDelegate: RemoteTableReloadDelegate?

    func levelCompleted() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(..., forKey: Const.completedShabbosLevels)
        remoteDelegate?.reload() // Concerning line 2/2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there shouldn't be a memory leak, however why don't you  set the remoteDelegate to self?

```
    shabbosVC.remoteDelegate = tableView.delegate as? any RemoteTableReloadDelegate
```

Your delegation is referenced weak in ShabbosViewController, I don't see any problems.

Tip: wrapping tableView.reloadTable() in mainQueue would be better, because it seems like your reload action will happen whenever tableview is not on the current view.

Comment: What do you mean by "set remoteDelegate to self"? Re: Tip: well, I do want it to happen _before_ the user sees that table again. wouldn't a mainQueue cause the reload to wait until the view is visible?

Comment: you can just  shabbosVC.remoteDelegate = self, because the self here conforms RemoteTableReloadDelegate and it is also equal to tableView.delegate.
If you want table to reload before user sees that table again, you should make it in mainQueue otherwise it will throw you purple warnings about memory. UI related actions should be in main thread. however, when you try to reload a table which is not visible at that time, this will happen in another threads by default. You need to carry that to main thread